# How to log simple debug messages to a file in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to be able to write debug messages to a log file. What is the proper way of doing this? There is absolutely no documentation that i can find out there. I know the Monolog bundle is mentioned but it is not writing anything. Please suggest.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html

Comment: i follow the steps but nothings gets logged ???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Assuming that you are using **MonologBundle** that is included by default*

### Step 1

Define your handler service and pass directory/file there

```
your.log.handler:
    class: %monolog.handler.stream.class%
    arguments: [ %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.yourFileName.log ]
```

Class parameter `%monolog.handler.stream.class%` is defined in **MonologBundle** and it is `Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler` class

### Step 2

Define your logger service and inject your handler there

```
your.logger:
    class: %monolog.logger.class%
    arguments: [ nameOfLoggingChannel ]
    calls: [ [pushHandler, [@your.log.handler]] ]
```

Parameter `%monolog.logger.class%` is also defined in **MonologBundle** and represents the `Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger` class

### Step 3

Inject it to your controller in  and use as normal logger

```
$logger = $this->get('your.logger');
$logger->warn('We are using custom logger');
```

Check your `app/logs/dev.yourFileName.log`

Comment: InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "log_handler" (in /Users/myuser/Sites/myapp.com/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "your.log.handler", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "assetic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "fos_user", "fos_rest", "jms_serializer", "main_user", "main_classified", "doctrine_mongodb", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"

Comment: sorry Im fairly new to Symfony @thecatontheflat

Comment: oops had to put steps1 and step 2 under the services

Comment: now I get: ParseException: Unable to parse in "\/Users\/myuser\/Sites\/myapp.com\/app\/config\/config.yml" at line 110 (near " arguments: [ nameOfLoggingChannel ]").

Comment: @jini could you create a chat, so I'll instruct you? :)

Comment: @VitaliyZurian: could you added those to your answer? I am facing the same problem and it seems like your answer is missing some steps, thanks!

Comment: @Zennichimaro what is the problem exactly? You can invite me to chat so we could check your problem

Comment: Thanks VitaliyZurian, my problem was exactly the same as @jini face, noobs problem.. I had no idea where to place those codes.. but I've figured out and have just add those to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

add 2 use classes

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
```

then in function simple use this

```
$log = new Logger('shipment');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('var/log/fileName.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('qty is 0', ['data' => 3]);
```